# MongoDB balancer is not redistributing documents automatically

Tags: mongodb

I just added a new replicaset shard following the documentation and activated sharding on my database but it seems data is not being redistributed across the 2 shards.
I have run the following commands once I had the 2 shards:

```
sh.enableSharding("app")
sh.shardCollection("app.rooms", { _id: 1 })
sh.shardCollection("app.messages", { r: 1 })
```

This is my shards' status:

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5374d041208075ddc590b642")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard1",  "host" : "shard1/ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "shard2",  "host" : "shard2/ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "app",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard1" }
        app.messages
            shard key: { "r" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard1  2018
            too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
        app.rooms
            shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard1  3
            { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : "PIn7KMxI" } on : shard1 Timestamp(1, 0)
            { "_id" : "PIn7KMxI" } -->> { "_id" : "pb7eAsMG" } on : shard1 Timestamp(1, 1)
            { "_id" : "pb7eAsMG" } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard1 Timestamp(1, 2)
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard1" }
```

The verbose version is available here: http://pastebin.com/ipz7pqPB

So it looks like all chunks were mapped to the first shard only. This looks good at first because all the data is in shard1 at the moment.

Now, I would like mongodb to migrate half of the chunks from shard1 to shard2 like it should do automatically as written [in the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/).

This is supposed to be the role of the balancer, which is running according to the result of this command:

```
mongos> sh.getBalancerState()
true
```

I am kind of stuck here as the documentation does not go any further explaining how the balancer works.

Comment: what's the output to sh.isBalancerRunning()?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I checked too, it returns true. Isn't it an alias of getBalancerState ?

Comment: no, balance state says "is it stopped or not stopped" (true means not stopped, that is, it *can* run). isBalancerRunning is whether it's actually running at this very moment - so it is.  And apparently it's taking a long time since you are not seeing any successful migrations.  Are the shards replica sets?  If they are, is replication lagging?  If it is, then it will cause migrations to be very slow.

Comment: Ok thx for the clarification @AsyaKamsky. I have actually added a 3rd replicaset shard and even though getBalancerState is always true, isBalancerRunning value changes every few seconds, so I'm not sure what I'm experiencing now, will investigate ;)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yes all shards are replicaset (with 3 members). I think the migration is not running as the database is still empty on the new shards' primaries. What is bugging me though is that both primaries created a local database of 94GB even though it did not receive any data yet. db.currentOp() on thoses primarues shows many short running operation of type 'getmore' on namespace 'local.oplog.rs' but according to my monitoring tool they are not moving much data (60KB/s)

Comment: 60KB/min actually, so nothing really.

Comment: Can you log into a mongos, switch to the config database and look at the changelog collection? You will want to look for anything with {"what":"moveChunk.start"} or {"what":"moveChunk.commit"} - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/config-database/

Comment: actually, the reason you have huge local DB is because you didn't specify the size of the oplog so it allocated 5% by default. You can fix that by wiping it out, and re-initializing that replica set but starting it up with --oplogSize <someNumberInMBs>

Comment: @JohnPetrone I don't have anything with moveChunk.start or moveChunk.commit. However I have plenty of moveChunk.from all having a worrying: "step 1 of 6" : 0, "note" : "aborted"

Comment: Ok looking at the logs I think I found my issue here: [Balancer] balancer move failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "error locking distributed lock for migration migrate-{ r: MinKey } :: caused by :: 13651 error checking clock skew of cluster ec2-X.X.X.X.eu-wes..." } from: shard1 to: shard2 chunk:  min: { r: MinKey } max: { r: "00USTqSk" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue here was that my servers' clock were not synchronized.
I installed `ntp` on all hosts and it fixed the issue!